# Google Play , YouTube and Gmail show error message “No Connection – Retry”

Tags: google-play-store, gmail, connection-issues, google, youtube

Some Android apps (like Google Play, Google Chrome, Gmail, and YouTube) show an error message “No Connection – Retry”.

On the other hand, apps like Facebook, Messenger, and WhatsApp perform Okay and connect correctly to the network.

In Facebook, I can play videos, make posts, and search.
In Messenger and WhatsApp, I can send messages but I can't send images.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

1. Clear the Cache on your Android device

   To fight the No Connection – Retry error message on Google Play Store app on your Android devices, try to clear the Play Store cache since this could be a reason of this error of repeatedly getting this network error message.

   To do this, go to Settings > App, scroll down to All apps and finally to Google Play Store app. Open the app details and tap the Force stop button to reach to the cache clearing button namely Clear Cache.

   That’s all what you needed to do to clear out the app cache. Restart your app and you might have just got rid of the No Connection – Retry error message on the Google Play Store app.
2. Check Date / Time settings

   In case clearing the cache did not work out for you, there can be a minor glitch in your date and time settings causing the No Connection – Retry error message on Google Play Store app of your android devices. Check the time and date since a plenty of users were facing this network error message because of incorrect time settings.
3. Make sure to enter the correct Google / Gmail password

   Another solution is to check your Google / Gmail account password. Did you change it and forget to re-enter in on your Android device? Whenever you change your password your Android device gets a notification to re-enter it. As soon as you correctly enter your new password, your Android phone or tablet would be able to get all the Google services back on the device.
4. Still getting the No Connection – Retry error message on Google Play Store app?

   Do a factory reset!

   Of course this is the very last option to go for but you would have to do it if your Google Play Store app simply refuses to connect. Before resetting your Android device never forget to back up your data since factory reset would wipe out all the data.